# Tabs in ionic is not showing content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to show content.  I added custom code here manually on custom template file.

```
  <ion-content>


<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    My Content here 
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">
     My Content here 1
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
    My Content here 3
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I took example code from here

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/

I am able to see tabs, but not content.   And yes if i  follow sample app tab for ionic i am able to do this. But i need above one.

Can we show content here.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the content inside ion-tab within div or some element (<div>My Content here 1</div>)? It looks like some classes are added to child element for ion-tab. Also can you try without ion-header-bar if it is there

Comment: i tried this. Still not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a view to load content within the tabs directive.  The route state uses the name of the view to place the content that will reside within the tab.

```
// Notice the referenced view is "home-tab"
.state('tabs.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
    }
  }
})

// Which correlates to the name of the view, which is also "home-tab"
<ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
  <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

You can add it easily within the same file (like in the example) using a template, which correlates using the templateUrl of the route to the id of the template in the markup:

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>
        // Your content
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

For a bit more information on setting up tabs in ionic there's also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889569/1148107).

Answer (score 3):

If you study the example closely you'll see that, each tab entry contains a `ion-nav-view` and each `nav-view` is actually a `ion-view` with `ion-content` that specify its contents.

In your code, tab elements are wrapped inside a `ion-content` which is actually the opposite way.

Here is a slightly simplified example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbOLzY

Comment: yes.. but i dont want to use ion-nav-view.

Can't be do in above example

Comment: I could kiss you, been having this problem for hours, your answer helped resolved my issue.