# Not displaying "ion-tab" in page detail

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

I have a problem, i have a code that I have displayed item which lead me to a page where shows detail of each item but this page does not show me the " ion -tab "

Any help

Thank You

Annex codes:

router:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider){     
    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle("center");       
    $stateProvider
        .state("app",{
            templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true
        })
        .state("app.noticias", {
            url: "/noticias",
            views: {
                "app-noticias":{
                    templateUrl: "templates/noticias.html",
                    controller: "noticiasCtrl"
                }
            }
        })                  
        .state('forgotpassword', {
          url: "/forgot-password/:id?tit?bgd?fec?com",
          templateUrl: "templates/forgot-password.html"
        })          
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/noticias");

})
```

code:

```
<ion-view title="Noticias">    
    <ion-content ng-controller="noticiasCtrl" style="top:0">              
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in rawData.slice(1, n)" class="item-noticias overlay" ng-style="{'background':'url(img/'+item.bg +') no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}">                
                <div class="overlay" ui-sref="forgotpassword({ id: item.tipo, tit: item.titulo, bgd:item.bgdetail, com:item.com, fec:item.fec })">       
                    <span class="tipo">{{ item.tipo }}</span>
                    <span class="titulo">{{ item.titulo }}</span>
                    <span class="link">Leer mas <img src="img/right-arrow.png"></span>                    
                </div>                        
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>             
      </ion-content>    
</ion-view>
```

Page detail:

```
<ion-view title="forgotpassword">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button" ng-click="$ionicGoBack($event)"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content ng-controller="noticiasCtrl" style="top:0">    
    <div class="header-image" ng-style="{'background':'url(img/'+bgd +') no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}">
    <div class="overlayPrinD"> 
      <div class="overlayPrinSecD">                 
            <span class="tipo">{{ id }}</span>
            <span class="titulo">{{ tit }}</span>                               
      </div>                
    </div>       
  </div>
  <p class="fec">{{ fec }}</p>
  <p class="texto">{{ com }}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using the ion-tab directive anywhere in the markup.  I can't tell from your question which views are supposed to be in the tabs, so here's generic solution you can use as an example:

```
// Routes
.state('dashboard.tabs', {
    url: "/tabs",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tab-container.html"
})

.state('dashboard.tab1', {
    url: "/tab1",
    views: {
        'tab1-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/tab1.html",
            controller: 'Tab1Ctrl as vm',
        }
    }
})

.state('dashboard.tab2', {
    url: "/tab2",
    views: {
        'tab2-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/tabs2.html",
            controller: 'Tab2Ctrl as vm',
        }
    }
})

// Tab markup for tab-container.html template
<ion-view view-title="Some Title">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">

        <ion-tab title="Tab 1" ui-sref="some.route.item1">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab1-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Tab 2" ui-sref="some.route.item2">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab2-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>

// Tab1 and/or Tab2 templates
<ion-view view-title="Tab #">
    <ion-content>
        // Your content
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

You could also include the individual tab markup in the container template using script tags with ng-template.

```
<script id="templates/tab1.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Tab 1">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>
        // Your content
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```